# How can I pass last stream value to error handler?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

Let's say I have the following synchronous code that requires original arguments when handling errors:

```
var input = createInput(123);

try {
  doWork(input);
} catch (err) {
  handleError(input, err); // error handling requires input
}
```

What is the best way to pass the original arguments to the error hander?

```
Rx.Observable.just(123).map(createInput).map(doWork).subscribe(
  function(result) {
    // success
  }, 
  function(err) {
    // how can I get the argument of doWork (the result of createInput) here?
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as a property of the Error object before you throw it or in wrapper code like below.

```
...map(function (value) {
    try {
        return createInput(value);
    }
    catch (e) {
        e.lastValue = value;
        throw e;
    }
}).subscribe(..., function (e) {
    e.lastValue...
```

Comment: It looks like I distilled the example in my questions a bit too much. In reality `doWork` is asynchronous, i.e. `Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(doWork)`. I ended up wrapping `doWork` to enrich the error with the original input. It works, but I was hoping for some stream "magic" that would avoid wrapping the async call.

Comment: yeah there's no Rx magic for this.  It is really just basic exception logic.  The best "Rx" magic you could do is insert a `.do(function(v) { someVariableInScope = v; })` clause just before your `map` operation and then access that variable in your error handler.  But that is fairly evil.